# One function for many buttons

Tags: javascript, oop

I have dynamically created elements on the page, a picture and three buttons which are created upon clicking the main button.

All of this works, but now I am trying to change the display on the dynamically created `div` with the pics to "none".

More than one issue arises here for me, first I cannot find out how to make the `div` "images" the target, or select it.

I am trying to get one function to do this for all the elements, they are all structured equally just the pictures are different.

```
function hidePic(arrayPos){
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton") + "[" + arrayPos + "]",
    finalTarget = elem.getElementsByClassName("images")[0];
    finalTarget.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    hidePic(0);
});
```

This is the relevant code, lines 4 to 10. If this is commented out, the rest of the code works, but as it is I get entirely unrelated errors in dev Tools.

Click this link to see [Codepen](http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB).

So the question is, how can I best implement the above code?

Comment: id should be unique in the same document.

Comment: @Zakaria, thanks, I know, it was a blunder, just started adding className to the elements before i posted the question. But thanks for any pointers, god knows I'm no stranger to errors :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just working on the code above you can do this in order to make it work for all instances. First let me point out that this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton") + "[" + arrayPos + "]";
```

will never work. That line is building a string. What you really want to make that line work is:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton")[arrayPos];
```

But even that I find unnecessary. Take a look at this code.

```
function hidePic (elem) {
    var finalTarget = elem.getElementsByClassName("images")[0];
    finalTarget.style.display = "none";
}

var closingButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton");
var index = 0, length = closingButtons.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    closingButtons[index].addEventListener("click",
        function () {
            hidePic(this);
        }
    );
}
```

This first finds all elements with the class `closingButton`. Then for each one we attach a click event listener. Instead of attempting to pass some index to this `hidePic` function we already have our function context which is what you seem to be trying to find in the function so lets just pass that and use it to find the image inside.

Let me know if you have any questions. I took a look at your codepen as well. I am not sure you should be forcing all that interactive HTML into a button element honestly, which itself is considered an interactive element. Not sure that meets the HTML spec. Perhaps add that HTML below the button. I bet when you click on things inside of that button it will register as clicks on the button as well unless you remove the event upon inserting your elements but then it seems like its getting too complicated for the simple stuff you are trying to do here.

Comment: You got there just before me! Can I suggest using the "range for"/"for/in" loop `for( var index in closingButtons)` instead of declaring all the variables? It's a lot simpler and I'm not aware of any optimisation loss.

Comment: Yea I prefer the normal for loop which is faster really. In this small subset, you are most likely correct that you wouldn't "see" any kind of performance loss. I save the for/in when I am actually iterating over object properties.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace,
Thanks a lot. Haha, when i have typed this part "[" + arrayPos + "]"; it felt so wrong, but it was the best I came up with:-)
Indeed I have anticipated that clicking on the new buttons will likely propagate/bubble all over the place, I will "insertafter() the dynamicaly created elements and leave the top button alone.Agree, this would become too complicated, this started as basic creating elements exercise originally.
One more thing, is it possible to set the display none with a settimeout?

Comment: @damianocelent Sure don't see why not. As long as you keep the element in scope for use in the timeout callback.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace, what I mean is, will it give a nice fade out effect or just abruptly disappear when the settimeout has passed?
Btw, I have tried your function, very nice way to resolve this issue, however, something is not right. Are you sure the this reference, in this context, refers to the images class? As it is, the image is not set to display none, you can check the pen. And predictably, clicking this button creates another element, totally my fault.:-) I will not do it, but just asking, how would you apply prevent bubbling here?

Comment: `this` refers to the `closingButton` that was clicked. Then we use that to find the `images` class inside it. I think you aren't seeing it work because of event bubbling. You can try to stop it using `event.stopPropagation()` but again the best way is to handle this by placing this stuff outside of your button. Then you won't need to do any tricky javascript. As for the setTimeout it will simply make the element disappear. You could use a setInterval and parsing the opacity and subtracting .1 of it each time. Once its 0 clear the interval and set display none. That would look like a fade out.

Comment: @damianocelent Here, this doesn't work perfectly because I am not 100% sure on everything you are trying to achieve but your code seems to be trying to attach events before those elements exist. If what I guess is correct then you also need to get the `parentNode` to find the images element. I moved the attach event into the function where its created and inserted into DOM and then stopped event bubbling from happening. https://jsfiddle.net/jvp6xe4n/

Comment: @AtheistP3ace
I was about to ask this, I have asked someone else before if you can just add eventlisteners to dynamically created elements and was told you can.
I knew i jquery you cannot, and need $(document).on("click", element, function etc.
So after all, need to find the parent element, create one eventlistener, and then intercept the propagation, I guess propagation must be stopped at parent element,right?
This is some high quality troubleshooting, learned plenty today from you :-)

Comment: @damianocelent You can add event listeners to dynamically created elements but not before they are created. What you are referring to in jQuery is called delegated events which is not what you were doing in your code. Your code was selecting a list of elements that didn't exist yet. jQuery's code is attaching the event to an existing element that will pass the event to the selector if that selector returns an existing element.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace
I have changed the main function, the whole thing is starting to look pretty good. I am not sure if the following queries justify a new answer, probably yes. Either way, setting display to none wit setTimeout will not work, but in the function you will see, I have implemented something much better, akin to the jquery hide method.
Ok, now the issues. I did not know how to insert the new created element after the main button, tried something like 
    
   Element.prototype.appendAfter = function (element) {
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);
}, false;

Comment: But decided to use that for another practice project. What happens now is, on every click on the main button, the same new element is generated, no big deal, but I'd like this to happen only once. And, once the element is clicked away, another click on the nations buttons will neither create a new element again nor will it restore what was there.
The next step I want to implement is , on click of prev/next button, the img in the container is changed. Again, thx for your help, it' very appreciated.

Comment: @damianocelent Yes, thats exactly how you insert after an element, `referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);`. To stop the same thing being generated in the click event handler you can always check if that element exists in the DOM and if it does just return instead of creating it.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace
Thanks. But where would include that code?Both the reference node line and the the if condition and the return?

Comment: @damianocelent for me, I would create an area after all the buttons to display everything. Then you don't need to insert anything between buttons which could lead to things being pushed around oddly. All this code would go into the addImageInto function. Here is a quick example. Obviously it needs to be cleaned up a bit with styling and stuff but the general idea is there. https://jsfiddle.net/jvp6xe4n/3/

Comment: In that example I use the buttons ID as another class on the close button. That way we we can stop the current loaded button from adding duplicates but it won't stop other buttons from displaying their info. And when we load new info I always clear out the current HTML inside it. check out the fiddle and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The codepen complains because there is no element with the "closingButton" class, so it's trying to call addEventListener on nothing, but I'm doubting that's the actual error you're seeing.

It's also worth nothing that I think this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton") + "[" + arrayPos + "]",
```

is excessive.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("closingButton")[arrayPos];
```

should be sufficient. Also not the syntax error at the end of the same line: it should be `;` not `,`. If this is the error in your code it could explain why you were getting "unrelated errors" syntax errors can cause misleading problems that are supposedly in other areas of the code!

Lastly, I'd highly recommend using JQuery to do your selection magic - it's exactly what it was designed for. If you're averse to using JS libraries, fair enough, but it would make your code a lot simpler and you can have reasonable confidence that it will perform the tasks about as optimally as is possible.

Comment: Great minds think alike? +1 although I am anti adding JS libraries. I love what jQuery did for cross platform back in the day but if you are only working on latest browsers these days in my opinion its become almost useless. Now of course I say almost but I haven't found anything I couldn't do in plain old javascript lately that jQuery provides.

Comment: @I Stanley,
It's odd, in the pen, there is a ";" after that line, not sure why it shows a comma here.
The classname closingButton does exist, I have added it in the function, and it displays the additional css styles given.
Indeed, with jQuery most of this stuff would not be an issue, but this is deliberate vanila JS practice, I want to know as much as possible how jQuery works behind the scenes, apart from the selectors and,ajax and a poor animation method, the structure is the same. I am one of those who "learned" jQuery first and later on realized that vanilla JS not as hard as I thought.